# Recover from IntegrityError in SQLAlchemy

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

With:

```
class X(Base):
  __tablename__ = 'x'
  id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
  ys = relationship("Y")

class Y(Base):
  __tablename__ = 'y'
  id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
  data = Column(String, unique=True)
  x_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('x.id'), nullable=False)
```

if I do something like:

```
# x is instance of X
x.ys #=> ["x"]
x.ys.extend(["x", "y", "z", "a"])
session.save()
```

an `IntegrityError` gets raised (of course).

Is there any way to either (a) get an array of the conflicting issues (at time of exception, not with a new DB request) or (b) tell SQLAlchemy to keep going (in the example about, have `y, z, a` added?

(Yes, I'm going for some kind of "set" like behavior here and under Postgres, so if there's some other way to achieve this I'm all ears too.)

Comment: It amuses and frustrates me that relational databases are supposed to be all about sets, yet they make it incredibly hard to achieve some simple set operations. You appear to be attempting a sort of upsert/merge operation; maybe those terms will help you find out more with a search. It isn't fun I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to either (a) get an array of the conflicting issues

Not that I know of.

> (b)  tell SQLAlchemy to keep going

You can [nest transactions](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/ru/latest/core/connections.html#nesting-of-transaction-blocks) which will generate savepoints.

Have you also considered using `relationship("Y", collection_class=set)`? I know that doesn't remove the possibility of errors in the context of parallel execution but within a transaction it makes things easier.